# How can I put arrows in listview same line?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I make a project and ı stuck in there. 
In my design papers like that [image]

And I did't put the arrow as seem so I can do it just Text side.

Like that

[image]

**How can I put the Arrows ?**

My codes are

```
String[] maddeler = new String[] { "YÖNETİM KURULU BAŞKANI FİKRİ ÖZTÜRK'ÜN MESAJI", "GENEL MÜDÜR CÜNEYT AĞCA İLE RÖPORTAJ", "21. YILINDA OPET",
        "MİSYONUMUZ VİZYONUMUZ DEĞERLERİMİZ"};
ArrayList<String> maddelerListe = new ArrayList<String>();
maddelerListe.addAll( Arrays.asList(maddeler) );



listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, maddelerListe);





mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );

mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:

                Intent baskanlar =new Intent(getBaseContext(),BaskanlarSplash.class);
                startActivity(baskanlar);

                break;
            case 1:

                Intent baskanlar2=new Intent(getBaseContext(),BaskanlarSplash2.class);
                startActivity(baskanlar2);

                break;

            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"içerik bekleniyor",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"içerik bekleniyor",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

**My simplerow.xml **

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/homeBac"
    >
</TextView>
```

**This is my Listview Normaly**

```
 <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mainListView">

        </ListView>
```

If you can help my I'm be so greteful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the base layout of your simplerow a RelativeLayout and set the values kind of like this.  You can make the arrow a drawable ImageView if you'd prefer.  May have to change settings but this should work.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/homeBac" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/homeBac"
        android:text=">" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

**change the row to**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**and then change the adapter declaration to**

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = 
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow,R.id.rowTextView, maddelerListe);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your row layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_your_arrow"/>
</LinearLayout>
```